# How to execute parse cloud after each 5 minutes

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse in an ios app. We need a scheduled push notification implementation. but in ios , there is no API for scheduled push notification. So scheduled push notification can be achieved through cloud code. But we need that cloud code should  be called  after each five minutes.Somebody suggest me , How  can I get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Jobs -> Scheduled Jobs*. This option is available in the Parse Dashboard (in the Core tab).

First create your function in cloud code javascript (I assume you know how to do this)

```
Parse.Cloud.job("sendPushNotifications", function(request, status) {
    // your code here
)}
```

Now go to Scheduled Jobs. You will find options there to schedule the `sendPushNotifications`  function you just created.